# Linuxのタッチパッドジェスチャーでn本指ホールド+任意のキー(またはクリック)で設定するには？

Tags: linux, ubuntu

タイトルの通りですが、タッチパッドでn本指ホールドしながら任意のキーまたはクリックを発動条件にジェスチャーを設定したいです。
libinput-gesturesではスワイプアップやピンチインなどしか設定できず、任意のキーとの組み合わせでジェスチャーを設定することができませんでした。

例)
２本指でホールド+左クリック→右クリック
３本指でホールド+左クリック→コピー
３本指でホールド+右クリック→貼り付け
３本指でホールド+ctrlキー→指定したアプリケーションを起動

Comment: 設定しようとしているジェスチャーは、どのような環境であれば使えていたのでしょうか？例えばメーカー製PCの独自機能だったりしませんか？

Comment: 現在Waylandを使用していますが、x11では２本指でホールド+左クリックしたときに右クリックとして扱われました。 右クリックをしたいときに２本指でホールドしながら左クリックする癖がついてるので少なくともそれはWaylandでも使いたいです。他は、あったら便利かなと思い書いただけでそこまで重要ではありません。

Comment: キー(keypress)と併用可能なものに [Fusuma](https://iberianpig.github.io/posts/2021-04-26_introducing_new_fusuma_2_features/)あるけどどちらかというと, 「キー押しながら swipe すると ...」みたいな感じですが。(クリックは可能かどうか不明)